# Using PyFlink with LightGBM

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, lightgbm, flinkml, pyflink

Is it possible to use PyFlink with python machine learning libraries such as LightGBM for a streaming application? Is there any good example for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no complete example but you can take a loot at [Getting Started with Flink Python](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/getting-started/walkthroughs/python_table_api.html) and then take a look at how Python UDFs can be used: [UDFs in the Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/functions/udfs.html#scalar-functions).